# How I can do the SQL query using two tables

Tags: sql

I have these two tables:

1. `Users` - where we take County and City ID's by user ID
2. `Names_list` - where located both City or County names

**`Users`**

```
id | county | city
---+--------+-----
1  | 123    | 456
```

**`Names_list`**

```
id  | name
----+-----
123 | ABC
456 | DEF
```

Query:

```
SELECT Users.id as id,  
  Users.county as county, 
  Users.city as city,  
  Names_list.name as name1 
  Names_list.name as name2 
FROM `Users` 
LEFT JOIN Names_list ON (Names_list.id = Users.city) 
LEFT JOIN Names_list ON (Names_list.id = Users.county) 
WHERE Users.id = '1'
```

This output needs to be returned:

```
id | county | name1 | city | name2
---+-------+--------+------+------
1  | 123    | ABC   | 456  | DEF
```

But, output is wrong, of course. `Names_list.id` are duplicated. Needs to be another solution to return in one line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need aliases:

```
SELECT u.id as id, u.county as county, u.city as city,  
       nc.name as name1  nco.name as name2 
FROM `Users` u LEFT JOIN
     Names_list nc
     ON nc.id = u.city LEFT JOIN 
     Names_list nco
    ON nco.id = u.county
WHERE u.id = 1;  -- I'm guessing this is a number so am removing the single quotes.
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add different aliases to the two different. See live demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e55d914acf76406d7517e993b6c05c73) and sql below. Note that it would be cleaner to have an entity type structure to tell apart city vs country IDs.

```
with Users(id,country,city)
as
(
select 1,123,456
), Names_list(id,name)
as
(
select 123,'ABC' union all
select 456,'DEF'
)
select    Users.*,
          city.name as city,
          country.name as country
from      Users
left join Names_list as city
          on city.id = Users.city
left join Names_list as country
          on country.id = Users.country
where     Users.id = 1
```